# For...in loop not looping as expected

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am fetching json data using for...in loop. The loop works but it's only displaying a single set of data.

This is the piece of code I'm using...

```
for (var prop in props) {
    document.querySelector(propSelects[prop]).innerHTML = list[i][prop];
};
```

This is the whole function:

```
lists.open('GET', 'js/data.json', true)
lists.onload = function() {
    var list = JSON.parse(this.response);
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        props = {
            titles: 'a.title',
            descs: '.desc',
        };
        for (prop in props) {
            document.querySelector(props[prop]).innerHTML = list[i][prop];
        };
    }
}lists.send();
```

It is supposed to loop 10 times but it seems that it's only producing a single set of data. I know there's something wrong with my For...in loop but I can't seem to know what.  I am a newbie by the way.  Thank you.

Comment: what is the content of `list` - it should be an array of length 10 or more, each item in the array should be an object with `{titles: "something", descs: "something"}` - otherwise you'll get errors in the developer tools console

Comment: having said that, each iteration will replace exactly the same elements (the first `a.title` and `.desc` in the DOM) - i.e. you'll only see the LAST list "titles" and "descs" in your page

Comment: If you want a useful answer ... **what is the content of list**

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a data property to your html so your selector selects the right DOM element. You're always modifing the same, which is the first, element when you call `document.querySelector(props[prop]).innerHTML` so your html needs a property on it like `data-index` and then you can query with it too.

Or use a `innerHTML += ...`

Comment: That's why I designated props to assign the element. Also, innerHTML += ... did not work.

Comment: You misunderstand. Your code has no idea which of the 10 elements you want to modify inner html of. So you only ever get 1 set.